# Executing the console ( cmd ) inside a frame in Visual Studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'd like to run my console application in a frame inside the Visual Studio environment and not in a separate window with an external prompt like the default behaviour provides. Is that possible?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 ultimate on a Windows 7 32bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In the Visual Studio Options Dialog -> Debugging -> Check the "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window".

Maybe this is behavior you'd like.

Comment: no, i'd like to have the ability to read and write in the same frame, with this option enabled i only have the debugger output redirected on an internal frame in VS.